# Changing the brightness of a specific text widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

The docs say that the [brightness property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/brightness.html) sets:

> The overall theme brightness.
>
> The default TextStyle color for the textTheme is black if the theme is
> constructed with Brightness.light and white if the theme is
> constructed with Brightness.dark.

And that [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html):

> Applies a theme to descendant widgets.

But I can't seem to change the brightness of child text widgets by wrapping them in a `Theme`, and I don't understand why. Here's an example (using Flutter 2.5.2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "This should be white"
              ),
              Theme(
                data: ThemeData(
                  brightness: Brightness.light,
                  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "This should be black"
                )
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This produces:

[image]

Can someone explain why the bottom text isn't black, and how I can change the brightness of a specific text widget using theme brightness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the implementation of the `Text` widget you can see that its `effectiveTextStyle` is based on the value of `DefaultTextStyle.of(context)`

*text.dart:*

```dart
class Text extends StatelessWidget {
  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context);
    TextStyle? effectiveTextStyle = style;
    if (style == null || style!.inherit)
      effectiveTextStyle = defaultTextStyle.style.merge(style);

    // ...
  }
}
```

Also the documentation of `DefaultTextStyle` says the following:

> The text style to apply to descendant Text widgets which don't have an
> explicit style.

[source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html)

This default style is based on the theme data provided by `MaterialApp` this is why your text is still white.

Instead of overriding with `Theme` you can directly override the `DefaultTextStyle` to obtain the result you want:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  child: Text("This should be black"),
)
```

You want to use `Theme` to change the `TextStyle` of pre-made material widgets such as `ListTile` for example which are not relying on `DefaultTextStyle.of(context)`:

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(brightness: Brightness.light),
  child: const ListTile(title: Text('This should be black')),
),
```

Under the hood `ListTile` is exactly doing what is shown above when rendering its `title` widget (it is using `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle` which works the same as `DefaultTextStyle`):

*list_tile.dart*

```dart
// This is what you can find inside the build method
final TextStyle titleStyle = _titleTextStyle(theme, tileTheme);

// As you can see the default style is overrided with the value
// from _titleTextStyle
final Widget titleText = AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
  style: titleStyle,
  duration: kThemeChangeDuration,
  child: title ?? const SizedBox(),
);
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d9a41e09287d53155281781df02a2eec)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Theme data you set on Material App mean set for descendant widget tree. If you want change brightness for specific widget you can try wrap with container or sized box and set background color for it.

Comment: But isn't the `Theme` widget is supposed to override the theme on the `MaterialApp`? Also, I'm not trying to change the background colour, I'm trying to change the text colour.

Comment: @JamesAllen if you want to override it, you set theme on Material App then, you can try ThemeData.dark().copyWith(change text color here)